Python Skfuzzy. I want to utilize centroid
import numpy as np
import skfuzzy as fuzz
from skfuzzy import control as ctrl

# 입력 변수 정의
price = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(0, 101, 1), 'price')
distance = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(0, 101, 1), 'distance')

# 출력 변수 정의 (추천도)
recommendation = ctrl.Consequent(np.arange(0, 101, 1), 'recommendation')

# 퍼지 집합 정의
price['cheap'] = fuzz.trimf(price.universe, [0, 0, 50])
price['average'] = fuzz.trimf(price.universe, [0, 50, 100])
price['expensive'] = fuzz.trimf(price.universe, [50, 100, 100])

distance['near'] = fuzz.trimf(distance.universe, [0, 0, 50])
distance['medium'] = fuzz.trimf(distance.universe, [0, 50, 100])
distance['far'] = fuzz.trimf(distance.universe, [50, 100, 100])

recommendation['low'] = fuzz.trimf(recommendation.universe, [0, 0, 30])
recommendation['medium'] = fuzz.trimf(recommendation.universe, [10, 50, 80])
recommendation['high'] = fuzz.trimf(recommendation.universe, [50, 100, 100])

# 퍼지 규칙 정의
rule1 = ctrl.Rule(price['cheap'] & distance['near'], recommendation['high'])
rule2 = ctrl.Rule(price['cheap'] & distance['medium'], recommendation['medium'])
rule3 = ctrl.Rule(price['cheap'] & distance['far'], recommendation['low'])
rule4 = ctrl.Rule(price['average'] & distance['near'], recommendation['medium'])
rule5 = ctrl.Rule(price['average'] & distance['medium'], recommendation['low'])
rule6 = ctrl.Rule(price['average'] & distance['far'], recommendation['low'])
rule7 = ctrl.Rule(price['expensive'] & distance['near'], recommendation['low'])
rule8 = ctrl.Rule(price['expensive'] & distance['medium'], recommendation['low'])
rule9 = ctrl.Rule(price['expensive'] & distance['far'], recommendation['low'])

# 제어 시스템 생성
recommendation_ctrl = ctrl.ControlSystem([rule1, rule2, rule3, rule4, rule5, rule6, rule7, rule8, rule9])
recommendation_sim = ctrl.ControlSystemSimulation(recommendation_ctrl)

# 입력 값 설정
recommendation_sim.input['price'] = 30
recommendation_sim.input['distance'] = 20

# 퍼지 추론 수행
recommendation_sim.compute()

# 출력 값 얻기
recommendation_level = recommendation_sim.output['recommendation']
print(f"Recommendation Level: {recommendation_level:.2f}")

I am totally new to skfuzzy. I want to use centroid somehow to make the recommendation value better. Currently, the value is determined by the minimum membership value of price and distance. I want to utilize centroid of price and distance to make sense recommendation value more.
